# What does this PHP syntax mean? (question marks)

Tags: php, syntax, ternary-operator

What does this line of PHP code mean? That is, the question mark bit followed by true, colon, false?

```
return(isset($_SESSION['id'])) ? true : false;
```

Comment: Shorthand for if(a=b){c}else{d}

Comment: It's actually useless in this scenario. `return isset($_SESSION['id']);` does exactly the same thing. Someone was trying to get fancy and ended up looking like an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/ternary).

It's simply short-hand for:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id']))
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as:

```
if isset($_SESSION['id']) {
     return true;
} else {
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is for Ternary operators in PHP

It runs like  `(Condition to evalute) ?( Return result if condition is true) : (return result if condition is false)`

in your case r`eturn(isset($_SESSION['id'])) ? true : false;`

if  `$_SESSION['id']` is set it will return true and if session is not set it will return false.

`?` mark is equivalent for if statement while `:` is for else

It is short form of `if else` statement

link : http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Answer (score 0):

This is a ternary operator.short for

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){ 
   return true;
 }else{ return false;}
```

However this is useless because isset() already returns true or false

Answer (score -1):

`? boolean-condition [action] : [action]` is the [ternary conditional operator](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) and is short for:

`if ([condition]) { [action] } else { [action] }`

Comment: Surprised that a 9k+ user would answer a duplicate... :facepalm:

Comment: Rather disappointing that a user would whinge about it

Comment: Coming from the rep-beggar who has 9k+ but still answers duplicates -.-

Comment: (FYI - down vote wasn't me)

Comment: I'm helpful, so I answer.